# Can't import matplotlib in Python 2.7 on Windows 32 bit

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have many error's when I import matplotlib in Python. All the error's is from the program *init*.py of matplotlib

First:

So I download the whl file of this site: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#distribute
 Document: matplotlib-2.2.0rc1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

I opened the CMD and did: Python -m pip install matplotlib-2.2.0rc1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

This was succesfull (I tried the different versions but it give me always the same error's.)

So I opened Idle version 2.7.14 and tried to import matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib
```

And this gives me this error's:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\j.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named urllib.request
>>>
```

I don't understand why they give me error's in this program... 
By the way I supposed to work with python 2.7 not Python3 so this is not a solution...

Can someone help me?

Comment: The error tells you that urllib.request cannot be found. So you need to find out why this is the case (this has nothing to do with matplotlib). So first thing would be to see if `six` is correctly installed, try `import six`, `print six.__version__`.

Comment: import six;
print six.__version__;

Version 1.2.0

But I installed six the same way as matplotlib with pip. Document: six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 

Maybe have somewhere a other six file???

Comment: Since six is now at [version 1.11](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/), you may need to update it. Or find out why it says 1.2 if you installed 1.11. That is indeed strange.

Comment: There was hidding an other six file in my documents so now I can import matplotlib. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide an answer useful for future readers:

Matplotlib requires **six 1.10** or higher to work correctly.